# Safe value must use property binding on angular attribute

Tags: angular, sanitize

I've got this error:

`SafeValue must use [property]=binding: Line1 &#xa; Line2 &#xa; Line3 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

But actually I do bind it to a property:

`[attr.data-panel]="parentInfoBubbleText"`

and sanitize it like so:

`this.parentInfoBubbleText = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('Line1 &#xa; Line2 &#xa; Line3');`

Is there another way to property bind it to an attribute in Angular?

Comment: I don't think you need to sanitize an attribute property

Comment: the problem is that otherwise the line-breaks are filtered out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Simply use `\u000A` instead of `&#xa;` in the string and no sanitation is required.

e.g. `[attr.data-panel]="Line1 \u000A Line2 \u000A Line3"`